# Disable warning for calls to one function

Tags: visual-studio-2010, warnings, code-analysis

I'm getting the Code Analysis Warning **CA1303: Microsoft.Globalization, "Do not pass literals as localized parameters"** when I use a function like this:

```
Logger.Log("blabla");
```

I use this call in lots of places, but don't want to get the warning for this calls and still get it for other calls using literals as parameters, so disabling the warning in the project properties is not an option.

I can disable the warning for concrete calls with

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1303:DoNotPassLiteralsAsLocalizedParameters")]
```

but I would need to use it in every call to `Logger.Log()`.

Is there a way to mark the Log() function to not trigger this warning?

```
class Logger{
    [Don't trigger CA1303 on calls to this function]
    static void Log(String message){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be avoided by decorating either the method or the parameter with a `[System.ComponentModel.LocalizableAttribute][1]` that specifies that it is not localizable.  e.g.:

```
public static void Log([Localizable(false)] string message)
{
    //...
}
```